# How to pass IOrderedQueryable to method and append it to query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

How would I pass one or more lambda order by clauses to a method and append it to a linq to entities query like below? I don't want to pass in strings, which I've seen discussed before, it should be lambda expressions for maintainability/refactoring/compile support.

```
public IList<UserRating> GetUserRatings(int userId, IPager pager, IOrderedQueryable<UserRating> orderBy)
{
    return _userRatingRepository.Table.Where(a => a.UserId == userId).Skip(pager.Skip).Take(pager.PageSize). /* orderBy goes here */ .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres how I do it:

```
public IList<UserRating> GetUserRatings<TKey>(
    int userId, 
    IPager pager, 
    Func<UserRating, TKey> orderBy)
{
    return _userRatingRepository
        .Table
        .Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
        .Skip(pager.Skip)
        .Take(pager.PageSize)
        .OrderBy(orderBy)
        .ToList();
}
```

usage:

```
GetUserRatings(1,pager, u=> u.Id)
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to specify OrderBy, OrderByDescending, ThenBy, & ThenByDescending clauses? Depending on the code calling the function I need to do multiple orders with varying combinations of ascending vs descending which is why I was thinking of the _IOrderedQueryable_ class.

Comment: @StrandedPirate hmm if you want to do this much customisation, maybe inside the method is not the best place for this sort. You could remove the orderby completely from GetUserRatings and then tack an .OrderBy in when you actually use it. If you toList first the ordering will get done in memory not in SQL. If you return an IQueriable you can add the orderby and execute it in the database

Comment: @StrandedPirate If you do still want to do it in the method you could use something like `Tuple<SortDirection,Func<UserRating, TKey>> orderBy, params Tuple<SortDirection,Func<UserRating, TKey>>[] thenBy` but thats pretty complicated, i use something similar for running includes via my generic repository.